# How to use "rm -rf --no-preserve-root" in bash on Windows

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-10-v1607, rm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After turning on Developer mode and installing the `Windows Subsystem for Linux`, how can I use the `rm` command in the bash shell running in Administrator mode?

Example:

```
rm -rf --no-preserve-root C:/Windows/System32
```

Comment: Try removing the `C:` part. Linux doesn't use that stuff. (I'm not sure whether the linux subsystem allows that however)

Comment: **WARNING**: If it worked that command would break Windows ...

Comment: You are looking for `/mnt/c/...` but see the warning above.

Comment: @DavidPostill Using `/mnt/c/` might work while using Unix OS, but will the command work successfully when running in bash on Windows? Because I think Windows doesn't have the equivalent of `preserve-root`.

Comment: But.... uh... why? just run `format C:` from regular cmd

Comment: @c2416726 Yes it will. See my answer.

Comment: @Rahul2001 because `rm` command is a standard POSIX-compliant, and `format` is a closed-source proprietary implementation from Micro$oft.

Comment: @c2416726 does it matter as long as in the end you are just ruining the OS?

Comment: `--no-preserve-root` doesn’t do what you think it does.

Comment: @DanielB Are you sure? See my answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, it’s totally irrelevant here unless some implementation detail interferes with it. `--preserve-root`, the default, makes `rm` check what device mounted at `/`. It will then skip instances of that device when deleting. Because `/` should be different from `/mnt/c` (but then again, who knows), it shouldn’t make any difference here.

Comment: @DanielB Read my answer. `/` and `/mnt/c` behave differently when it comes to `rm -rf --no-preserve-root`. Running `rm ​-rf --no-​preserve-root "/​"` will only destroy your installation of the Windows Subsystem for Linux. `Running rm ​-rf --no-​preserve-root "/​mnt/c/windows/system32/"` will hose Windows.

Comment: Yeah, but that’s not what I’m referring to. I’m saying that `rm /mnt/c` and `rm --no-preserve-root /mnt/c` should perform exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I use the rm command in the bash shell running in Administrator mode?

> Example:
>
> ```
>  rm -rf --no-preserve-root C:/Windows/System32
> ```

### WARNING: Do not attempt the following.

When using bash in WLS you need to address drives by using the `mount` points, so `C:/` becomes `/mnt/c/`.

However, if you attempt to run the above command corrected as I have described you will **Destroy Windows**.

> While the command runs, you’ll start notice that Windows will revert to default program settings as applications and classic programs are fully or partially deleted from your system. You’ll also notice that customization such as themes and desktop backgrounds will start to drop out. If you haven’t realized it yet, your system is about to die.

Keep reading for all the gory details.

---

#### `rm -rf /` in Windows Subsystem for Linux reveals sharp set of teeth

> **Don’t run any commands mentioned in this article. They’re intentionally very destructive for your Windows system.**
>
> I had a go at running `rm ​-rf --no-​preserve-root "/​mnt/c"` in the new
>   Windows Subsystem for Linux. I knew I could interact with the full
>   file system and modify and delete files, but I didn’t expect it to be
>   as potent as it turned out to be.
>
> While the command runs, you’ll start notice that Windows will revert
>   to default program settings as applications and classic programs are
>   fully or partially deleted from your system. You’ll also notice that
>   customization such as themes and desktop backgrounds will start to
>   drop out. If you haven’t realized it yet, your system is about to die.
>
> Like when you run this command under a full Linux kernel, the system
>   will usually buckle before it manages to delete every file completely.
>   Files currently loaded by the Windows kernel and files not writable by
>   users in the Administrator user group in Windows will not be deleted.
>   That, however, will still delete large chunks of critical system files
>   and programs in Windows.
>
> Running the above command will delete some 12 000 files in the default
>   Windows installation directory at C:Windows as well as all user files
>   in C:Users and leave your system incapable of booting up again! While
>   you can still carry on working in the session for quite some time, it
>   will eventually stop responding and throw you into a blue screen. Upon
>   restarting, Windows will be missing drivers and other required files.
>
> Running `rm ​-rf --no-​preserve-root "/​"` will only destroy your
>   installation of the Windows Subsystem for Linux. Running `lxrun.exe /uninstall /full /y && lxrun.exe /install /y` in the Command Prompt
>   will reinstall it and have you back up and running in Ubuntu in no
>   time. It will not traverse the symlink to the Windows file system in
>   the mount point and start deleting things on your C: drive. Doing so
>   explicitly with the first command I mentioned, will not stop you from
>   gutting your system.

Source [rm -rf / in Windows Subsystem for Linux reveals sharp set of teeth](https://ctrl.blog/entry/rmrf-in-wsl)